# Security advice: SSL and API access

Tags: security, api, ssl, httpwebrequest, ssl-certificate

My API (a desktop application) communicates with my web app using basic HTTP authentication over SSL (Basically I'm just using https instead of http in the requests). My API has implemented logic that makes sure that users don't send incorrect information, but the problem I have is that someone could bypass the API and use curl to potentially post incorrect data (obtaining credentials is trivial since signing up on my web app is free).

I have thought about the following options:

1. Duplicate the API's logic in the web app so that even if users try to cheat the system using curl or some other tool they are presented with the same conditions.
2. Implement a further authentication check to make sure only my API can communicate with my web app. (Perhaps SSL client certificates?).
3. Encrypt the data (Base 64?)

I know I'm being a little paranoid about users spoofing my web app with curl-like tools but I'd rather be safe than sorry. Duplicating the logic is really painful and I would rather not do that. I don't know much about SSL client certificates, can I use them in conjunction with basic HTTP authentication? Will they make my requests take longer to process? What other options do I have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, there's no replacement for validations on the server side.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers, I'll go with server-side validation, however painful it may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL protects you from the man-in-the-middle attacks, but not from attacks originated on the client side of the SSL. A client certificate built into your client API would allow you to identify that data was crafted by the client side API, but will not help you figuring out if client side manually modified the data just before it got encrypted. Technically ssavy user on the client end can always find a way to modify data by debugging through your client side API.  The best you can do is to put roadblocks to your client side API, to make it harder to decipher it. Validation on the server side is indeed the way to go.

---

Consider refactoring your validation code so that it can be used on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree in general with sinelaw's comment that such validations are usually better on the server side to avoid exactly the kind of issue you're running into (supporting multiple client types).  That said, you may just not be in a position to move the logic, in which case you need to do something.

To me, your options are:

- Client-side certificates, as you suggest -- you're basically authenticating that the client is who (or what, in your case) you expect it to be.  I have worked with these before and mutual authentication configuration can be confusing.  I would not worry about the performance, as I think the first step is getting the behavior your want (correctness first).  Anyway, in general, while this option is feasible, it can be exasperating to set up, depending on your web container.
- Custom HTTP header in your desktop app, checking for its existence/value on the server side, or just leveraging of the existing User-Agent header.  Since you're encrypting the traffic, one should not be able to easily see the HTTP header you're sending, so you can set its name and value to whatever you want.  Checking for that on the server side is akin to assuring you that the client sending the request is almost certainly using your desktop app.

I would personally go the custom header route. It may not be 100% perfect, but if you're interested in **doing the simplest possible thing to mitigate the most risk**, it strikes me as the best route.  It's not a great option if you don't use HTTPS (because then anyone can see the header if they flip on a sniffer), but given that you do use HTTPS, it should work fine.

BTW, I think you may be confusing a few things -- HTTPS is going to give you encryption, but it doesn't necessarily involve (client) authentication.  Those are two different things, although they are often bundled together.  I'm assuming you're using HTTPS with authentication of the actual user (basic auth or whatever).

Comment: There's no point in having SSL without at least *some* authentication; otherwise you've got a secure connection to something totally random, and are thus vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. That's why the SSL protocol requires the server to prove its identity to the client, typically though providing either a known ident, a certificate chain from a trusted ident, or some kind of matching between ident and client-requested hostname. Or a combination of the two, naturally.

Comment: Agreed, but let me be clear that I am talking about client authentication, which I think was the point of the question. (he said basic authentication, which implies typical client authentication via username/password)

Answer (score 2):

*You **must** validate the data on the server side.* You can throw nasty errors back across the connection if the server-side validation fails — that's OK, they're not supposed to be tripped — but if you don't, you are totally vulnerable. (Think about it this way: it's the server's logic that you totally control, therefore it is the server's logic that has to make the definitive decisions about the validity of communications.)

Using client certificates won't really protect you much additionally from users who have permission to use the API in the first place; if nothing else, they can take apart the code to extract the client certificate (and it has to be readable to your client code to be usable at all). Nor will adding extra encryption; it makes things much more difficult for you (more things to go wrong) without adding much safety over that already provided by that SSL connection. (The scenario where adding encryption helps is when the messages sent over HTTPS have to go via untrusted proxies.)

Base-64 is not encryption. It's just a way of encoding bytes as easier-to-handle characters.